# Post's Completeness Theorem (Matlab Code)

Tags: logic, matlab

I am trying to finish a piece of Matlab 16 code which I have posted at the end. The objective is to evaluate each of the five properties for each Boolean operator specified by Emil Post in his thesis (some background can be found here https://sites.ualberta.ca/~francisp/Phil428/Phil428.11/UrquhartPost.pdf). The five conditions are listed at:

1) Easy to understand yet must log into Scribd unfortunately. 
https://www.scribd.com/document/255983069/Posts-Criterion

2) A little more difficult to follow but more rigorous. Pdf is readily available:
https://sites.ualberta.ca/~francisp/Phil428/Phil428.11/PostPellMartin.pdf

The five properties are that a Boolean function $f$ may have are:

- $f$ preserves zero $(T_0)$,
- $f$ preserves one $(T_1)$,
- $f$ is linear $(L)$,
- $f$ is monotone $(M)$,
- $f$ is self-dual $(S)$.

Post's Completeness Theorem may be stated as follows (This is straight from the first reference):

**Theorem.** *A system of Boolean functions is functionally complete if and only if this system does not entirely belong to any of $T_0$, $T_1$, $L$, $M$, $S$.*

This means that

- at least one function that does not preserve zero (i.e. it is not in $T_0$), and
- at least one function that does not preserve one (i.e. it is not in $T_1$), and
- at least one function that is not linear (i.e. it is not in L), and
- at least one function that is not monotone (i.e. it is not in M), and
- at least one function that is not self-dual (i.e. it is not in S).

The aforementioned documents spell these out in great detail so I will not belabor the point here. Post's Completeness Theorem, however, states that a functionally complete operator set is a set of operators which at least one function $f$ of the set does not entirely below to all of these sets 1 through 5.

As a way to attempt to validate my code the number of Sheffer functions, that is those functions which are complete by themselves (as NAND and NOR gates are) for arity $n$ is \begin{equation} 2^{2^n-2}-2^{2^{n-1}} \end{equation} and for for $n=3$, or Boolean functions of three variables, there should be 48 Sheffer functions. The code I am providing calculates on 43 Sheffer functions and therefore something is amiss.

A remark on the code. It is my first attempt at coding each of the five criteria and therefore it is not as clean as I typically prefer. My objective is to first get it working and then to make changes according to preferred programming conventions. For properties 1, 2, 3, and 5 the main loop runs through the functions one-by-one. For Property 4 this is unnecessary and so I wait to evaluate Property 4 until the very end.

If a Boolean function meets a property then it receives a $1$ for TRUE and a $0$ for FALSE in the Conditions matrix. The Conditions matrix is a $2^{2^n}$-by-5 Boolean matrix which keeps track of how the functions behaved for the 5 conditions. According to Post's conditions then, a Sheffer function should have a row of zeros since it fulfills none of the conditions and it does not entirely below to any set. The final loop at the end of the code is supposed to determine how many Sheffer functions there are. For the arity (AtomNum) within the code this should be 48.

I suspect the error is within Property 3 - linearity. I have rewritten each of the 5 and I am fairly confident that the other four are working as necessary. However, I have been wrong many times and this one could just be yet another one of those times.

Please let me know if something is not clear or is confusing. I will respond swiftly. Thank you for your help!

```
clear all
clc

AtomNum = 3; % Arity
Conditions(1:2^(2^AtomNum),1:5) = 0;

Q = '';
     for j = 0:2^(2^AtomNum)-1
         BString = dec2bin(j);
         for n=1:length(dec2bin(2^(2^AtomNum)-1))-length(dec2bin(j))
             BString = strcat('0',BString);
         end

     L = length(BString);

     % Test Properties according to Post's Completeness Theorem
     % Property 1: f preserves 0
     % 0: No
     % 1: Yes
     if BString(1) == '0'
        Conditions(j+1,1) = 1;
     end

     % Property 2: f preserves 1   
     % 0: No
     % 1: Yes
     if BString(length(BString)) == '1'
        Conditions(j+1,2) = 1;
     end

     % Property 5: Self-Dual?
     % 0: No
     % 1: Yes
     flag = 0;
     for k = 1:L/2
         if str2num(BString(k)) ~= 1-(str2num(BString(L-k+1)))
             flag = 1;
         end
     end
     if flag == 0
        Conditions(j+1,5) = 1;
     end


     %--------------------------------     
     % Property 3: Alternating Functions or Linearity
     % 0: No
     % 1: Yes

     % Initialize the A matrix
     A(1:2^AtomNum,1:AtomNum+1) = 0;

     F = dec2bin(j);
     L = length(F);
     for n = L:2^AtomNum-1
         F = strcat('0',F);
     end
     for jj = 1:2^AtomNum
         A(jj,AtomNum+1) = str2num(F(jj));
     end

     % This code produces the atom matrix, or A matrix
     % The B matrix is the A matrix augmented with the 
     % function's results
     for jj = 0:2^AtomNum-1
         BString1 = dec2bin(jj);
         L = length(BString1);
         for n = L:AtomNum-1
             BString1 = strcat('0',BString1);
         end
         for kk = 1:AtomNum
             A(1+jj,kk) = str2num(BString1(kk));
         end
     end

     % is any column has a 1,3 or a 0,2 then that
     % column has dummy variables and needs to 
     % be addressed
     for jj=1:AtomNum
         B(:,jj) = 2* A(:,jj) + A(:,AtomNum+1);
     end

     % We need to ignore all dummy variables. 
     % Those coded with a -1 are dummy variables
     for jj=1:AtomNum 
         if any(B(:,jj)==0) * any(B(:,jj)==2) == 1
            B(B(:,jj) == 0,jj) = -1;
            B(B(:,jj) == 2,jj) = -1;
         end
         if any(B(:,jj)==1) * any(B(:,jj)==3) == 1
            B(B(:,jj) == 1,jj) = -1;
            B(B(:,jj) == 3,jj) = -1;
         end
     end

     % set dummy variables values to -1
     for jj=1:2^AtomNum
         for k=1:AtomNum
             if B(jj,k) == -1
                A(jj,k) = -1;
             end
         end
     end

     % Set conditions as true. If an instance arises 
     % where it is false then set value as zero
     cond1 = 1;
     cond2 = 1;
     cond3 = 1;
     cond4 = 1;
     for jj=1:2^AtomNum
         if A(jj,1+AtomNum) == 1
            if mod(sum(A(A(jj,1:AtomNum)==1)),2) == 1
               cond1 = 0;
            end
         end
         if A(jj,1+AtomNum) == 0
            if mod(sum(A(A(jj,1:AtomNum)==1)),2) == 0
               cond2 = 0;
            end
         end

         if A(jj,1+AtomNum) == 1
            if mod(sum(A(A(jj,1:AtomNum)==1)),2) == 0
               cond3 = 0;
            end
         end
         if A(jj,1+AtomNum) == 0
            if mod(sum(A(A(jj,1:AtomNum)==1)),2) == 1
               cond4 = 0;
            end
         end
     end
     % Either cond1 AND cond2 must be true OR cond3 AND cond4
     % must be true to Property 3 to be true for this Boolean 
     % function.
     Conditions(j+1,3) = cond1*cond2+cond3*cond4;
end

%Principle 4: Monotonic Functions 
% 0: No
% 1: Yes
S = {'0', '1'};

for n = 1:AtomNum
  cnt = 0;
  J = {};
  for m = 1:numel(S)
    for k = m:numel(S)
      if bitor(bin2dec(S{m}), bin2dec(S{k})) == bin2dec(S{k})
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        J{cnt} = strcat(S{m},S{k}); 
      end
    end
  end
  S = J;
end

S = bin2dec(S);
Conditions(S+1,4) = 1;





% If all rows are zero then the function is a Sheffer function. 
% Count the number of Sheffer functions. For AtomNum=3 it should
% be 48.
cnt = 0;
for j=1:2^(2^AtomNum)
   if sum(Conditions(j,:)) == 0
       cnt = cnt + 1;
   end
end
```

Comment: I have not looked at the code yet and I'm not sure if this was just said wrong even though you have it right in your head, but the following is incorrect: "Post's Completeness Theorem, however, states that a functionally complete operator set is a set of operators which at least one function f of the set does not entirely belong to all of these sets 1 through 5."   ...This states that a functionally complete set could be for example, a singleton set, where the sole operator is one which does not possess exactly one of the 5 properties.

Comment: But this is not the case; Since it is a singleton set, the operator would need to not posses *any* of the 5 properties. The theorem really states that for each property, there must be an operator in the operator set which does not possess the given property (and it could be possible a single operator does not posses all 5 properties as opposed to 5 distinct operators each not possessing one of the 5 distinct properties).

Comment: Harry, Thank you for your feedback. I have expanded the section about Post's Completeness Theorem. It is located after the literature links. I think that my approach is still correct even though my explanation could still be a little off. Tell me what you think. I am still under the impression that there is an error in applying the concepts in the code rather than a misuse of the Theorem. However, I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Looks good.  But in regards to your actual question sorry, but I'm just not familiar enough with matlab to help you out. Perhaps also include pseudo-code for the program/the linearity part, so that the logic of the program could be more readily apparent?

Comment: Harry, will do. I will post it tonight. Thank you.

Comment: I went through the linearity property last night and fixed the code. Although I do still only get 43 Sheffer functions I noticed that if I disregard Property 5 - Duality, I do receive the number 48. I am starting to think that I am misinterpreting duality or I am misinterpreting how the condition needs to be enforced. I have validated each property manually for 2-arity and it matches exactly so I am still not entirely sure what the issue is. I will provide the corrected code at the end of the day.

Comment: Two updates: 1) The number of 3-ary Sheffer functions is actually 56. There must be a typo in the book I referenced. 2) The error is most definitely in my code for Principle 3 - Alternating Functions or Linearity. Until this condition I obtain 56 Sheffer functions.